# NodeJs, pattern for sync developement

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, synchronization

I am new with NodeJs and Express frameworks. I have understood that Node works with only one thread on the server side. So, I have noticed this causes me some problems in order to develop correctly my application.

In my routes folder, I have a file index.js.
This file manage the navigation asked by the user from app.js.

So I decided to create a route function "test".
In this function, I had just that code

```
exports.test = function(req, res){
   res.render('test', {});
};
```

So simple, so easy. That's rend the template test.jade in my views folder. Greats !
But I wanna complexify the process. In this test route function, I want load some content from my MYSQL database.

For that, I have created a folder **Models** in the folders **node_modules**
Inside, I have only 2 file, the first **mysqlConnection.js** which exports the variable DB in order to make queries.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var DB = mysql.createConnection(
   {
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : '',
      database : 'test',    
   }
);

DB.connect();
module.exports = DB;
```

In the second file, **articles_class.js**, I just have

```
var DB = require('models/mysqlConnection');

var Article = function() {

this.getArticles = function()
{
    DB.query('SELECT * FROM articles;', function(err, rows, fields) 
    {
        if (err) 
            throw err;
        else
        {
            console.log(rows);
            return (rows);
        }
    });
}
}

module.exports = Article;
```

Go back in my route test function :

I just want to load from table "test" all the articles. Very basic. But not easy.
Why ?
Because before the query is finished, NodeJs respond to the client with the template render, but, unfornlty, without the rows loaded. Asynchronous problem ... Mysql doesn't block the Nodejs javascript Instruction.

The code of the function  :

```
exports.test = function(req, res){

var Article = require('models/articles_class');
a = new Article();
articles = a.getArticles();

console.log(articles); // undefined

res.render('test', {});
};
```

I Found others subjects in stackoverflow which speak about this problem. Make sync queries, work with callbacks ect ..
But for, here, if I try to manage this problem with callbacks, That's cannot work ... Because I need to send to the client the template with articles but I can't block the process with a sync method.

I am very lost ... I don't understand how I have to build my application. I am not able to create a good proceed in order to manage the sql queries. There is a pattern or a specific method ?

Or perhaps I have to make only ajax requests from the client. I load the template "test". And in a javascript file in the public folder, I ask to the server to load me the articles content and wait success callback function ? it's not very clean ...

Thx for your answers. The others answers I have found didn't help me to understand how manage that with NodeJs.

Comment: +1 vote because of the good description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a callback to getArticles:

```
exports.test = function(req, res){

  var Article = require('models/articles_class');
  a = new Article();
  a.getArticles( function( articles ) {
    console.log(articles); // undefined
    res.render('test', { articles: articles });
  });

};
```

---

Changes to your get articles function:

```
var DB = require('models/mysqlConnection');

var Article = function() {

this.getArticles = function( callback )
{
    DB.query('SELECT * FROM articles;', function(err, rows, fields) 
    {
        if (err) 
            throw err;
        else
        { 
            console.log(rows);
            callback && callback(rows);
        }
    });
}
}

module.exports = Article;
```

---

Express will only return the template through the open http connection once res.render() is called. So it's just a matter of passing it as a callback through your call stack, so it should only be called after you have your database rows.

As we are working with callbacks, they don't block your application.

Comment: Ok thx al lot that works.
But I need to understand. The callback is blocking the nodeJs process ?

Comment: No, they don't block. Node is an event oriented server, so it should never block (thus passing callbacks around). You gave a callback to DB.query, which will be executed once the query is returned, then that also contains the callback you want to execute to render.